# CloudFormation Pseudo Parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm making an AWS CodeStar project and I created my template.yml who contains my Lambda functions, SF, DynamoDB tables.

If I type the region and the account ID hardcoded it works but when I replace them with parameters like `${AWS::Region}` or `${AWS::AccountId}` i get this error:

> Failed to execute change set. Current stack status: UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE. Reason: No reason was provided.

This is a portion of my `template.yml`

```
Resources:

  DataAgentIntercept:
    Type: AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine
    Properties:
      StateMachineName: DataAgentIntercept
      DefinitionString: |-
        {
          "StartAt": "InsertAgentDataDB",
          "States": {
            "InsertAgentDataDB": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:awscodestar-pocawsjawa-lambda-InsertAgentDataDB-10UOAYKYNWLYB",
              "End": true
            }
          }
        }
      RoleArn: arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/service-role/StatesExecutionRole-eu-west-1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default strings are just literal values. If you want to perform any substitutions, you need to use [Fn::Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) (in YAML you can use shorthand notaiton `!Sub`):

```
  StateMachineName: DataAgentIntercept
  DefinitionString: !Sub |-
    {
      "StartAt": "InsertAgentDataDB",
      "States": {
        "InsertAgentDataDB": {
          "Type": "Task",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:awscodestar-pocawsjawa-lambda-InsertAgentDataDB-10UOAYKYNWLYB",
          "End": true
        }
      }
    }
  RoleArn: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/service-role/StatesExecutionRole-eu-west-1"
```